# Is the new live-action Ghost In The Shell movie a composite?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-2017, ghost-in-the-shell

Inspired by this question: [Differences between the Ghost in the Shell anime and Live action](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/40654)

I'm wondering if the new movie was meant to be a mash-up of everything in the GitS universe? Details below.

I recently watched the new 2017 *Ghost in the Shell* (Scarlett Johansen) and noticed it started very similar to the original movie, but it ended quite differently. I was wondering if they, perhaps, made the movie to encompass the later anime movies and series, trying to make it into one stand-alone story?

I've seen there is a series *GitS:Stand Alone Complex*, and another movie *GitS:Arise*, though I haven't seen either yet.

My question is: Does the new live-action GitS contain any elements from the second series or movies? Or did they just make up everything that didn't fit with the original movie? Quotes from the writers or director would be ideal.

Comment: They took a lot of scenes from the 1st movie and then mashed up some original work on top of it. I do not recall scenes other than from the 1st movie. I'll try to make an answer later on

Comment: I think the visual of the "exploded view geishas" is from "GITS2: Innocence." While that story line is--at its most basic--from the manga. One might consider it a mashup in that I do not think it was in the first movie adaptation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the live action movie drew from the first GitS anime movie - they took the main plotline of the PuppetMaster and the sequence of scenes (jumping off the building, the various "puppets", the diving underwater, the final fight involving the tank). All of the Section 9 characters and their backgrounds (with the exception of Killian/Kusanagi) are from the first movie (although, the chief does take a level in badass for the live action).

However, some elements from the later movies/series also added in - the geishas, for example. Also, the main antagonist combines elements from multiple sources:

> he hacks into people's minds like the PuppetMaster from the first movie, but is not an emergent AI. He is a cyborg with similar background to the Major, and incorporates elements of the Laughing Man.

Also, Kusanagi's background seems to be an invention for the new movie.

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you that at least Johan Philip Asbæk, who plays Batou, was aiming for that composite you're talking about based on [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_ZnKXlc6YU?start=1093&end=1160). Based on the fact that he had the creative freedom to do that, I assume, and only assume, the general vibe of the production was more of a composite movie than a faithful rendition of either the original movie or the mangas.

What I do know, is that the storyline presented in the 2017 movie was not shown very clearly in any of the medias. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoko_Kusanagi#Background) says that Motoko's (or Mira's) background was only hinted at through some flashbacks of her past, but never directly followed like in the new movie.